# How do I convert kotlin data class to xml using fasterxml?

Tags: xml, spring-boot, kotlin, fasterxml, data-class

I have a kotlin data class that I would like to serialize to xml. I am using Jackson Fasterxml. However, when I serialize the class, the JacksonXmlProperty is ignored thus not giving the desired output. Here's the data class I was working on.

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "COMMAND")
data class Request(
        @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "TYPE")
        val type: String,

        @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "INTERFACEID")
        val interfaceId: String,

        @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "MSISDN")
        val msisdn: String,

        @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "MSISDN2")
        val msisdn2: String,

        @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "AMOUNT")
        val amount: Int,

        @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "MEMO")
        val memo: String,

        @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "EXTTRID")
        val externalTxnId: String,

        @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "MERCHANT_TXN_ID")
        val merchantTxnId: String,

        @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "IS_TRANS_UNIQUE_CHECK_REQUIRED")
        val isUnique: String = "Y",

        @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "REFERENCE")
        val reference: String,

        @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "serviceType")
        val serviceType: String,

        @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "USERNAME")
        val username: String,

        @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "PASSWORD")
        val password: String
)
```

The response I was getting ignores the JacksonXmlProperty:

```
<COMMAND>
  <serviceType>MERCHPAY</serviceType>
  <type>MERCHPAY</type>
  <interfaceId>DATABUNDLES</interfaceId>
  <msisdn>733204938</msisdn>
  <msisdn2>100001929</msisdn2>
  <amount>1000</amount>
  <memo>Enter the PIN for payment of 1000 to purchase testing transaction</memo>
  <externalTxnId>07026984141550752666</externalTxnId>
  <merchantTxnId>07026984141550752666</merchantTxnId>
  <reference>Testing transaction</reference>
  <username>abcd</username>
  <password>abcd123</password>
</COMMAND>
```

Answer (score 1):

To convert kotlin data class to xml using fasterxml

1. Ensure you add dependency on pom

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

2. On the data class add `@field` so that the `@JacksonXmlProperty` is not ignored

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "COMMAND")
data class AirtelExpressRequest(
        @field:JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "TYPE")
        val type: String,

        @field:JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "INTERFACEID")
        val interfaceId: String,

        @field:JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "MSISDN")
        val msisdn: String,

        @field:JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "MSISDN2")
        val msisdn2: String,

        @field:JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "AMOUNT")
        val amount: Int,

        @field:JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "MEMO")
        val memo: String,

        @field:JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "EXTTRID")
        val externalTxnId: String,

        @field:JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "MERCHANT_TXN_ID")
        val merchantTxnId: String,

        @field:JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "IS_TRANS_UNIQUE_CHECK_REQUIRED")
        val isUnique: String = "Y",

        @field:JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "REFERENCE")
        val reference: String,

        @field:JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "serviceType")
        val serviceType: String,

        @field:JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "USERNAME")
        val username: String,

        @field:JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "PASSWORD")
        val password: String
)
```

3. Using `XmlMapper` you can then go ahead and serialize to the data class to xml

```
 val xmlMapper = XmlMapper(
                JacksonXmlModule().apply { setDefaultUseWrapper(false) }
        ).apply {
                enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)
        }
val strObject = Request(
                type            = "MERCHPAY",
                interfaceId     = "DATABUNDLES",
                msisdn          = "733204938",
                msisdn2         = "100001929",
                amount          = 1_000,
                externalTxnId   = "07026984141550752666",
                merchantTxnId   = "07026984141550752666",
                reference       = "Testing transaction",
                memo            = "Enter the PIN for payment of 1000 to purchase testing transaction",
                serviceType     = "MERCHPAY",
                username        = "abcd",
                password        = "abcd123"
        )
        val xml = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(strObject)
```

4. Output

```
<COMMAND>
  <TYPE>MERCHPAY</TYPE>
  <INTERFACEID>DATABUNDLES</INTERFACEID>
  <MSISDN>733204938</MSISDN>
  <MSISDN2>100001929</MSISDN2>
  <AMOUNT>1000</AMOUNT>
  <MEMO>Enter the PIN for payment of 1000 to purchase testing transaction</MEMO>
  <EXTTRID>07026984141550752666</EXTTRID>
  <MERCHANT_TXN_ID>07026984141550752666</MERCHANT_TXN_ID>
  <IS_TRANS_UNIQUE_CHECK_REQUIRED>Y</IS_TRANS_UNIQUE_CHECK_REQUIRED>
  <REFERENCE>Testing transaction</REFERENCE>
  <serviceType>MERCHPAY</serviceType>
  <USERNAME>abcd</USERNAME>
  <PASSWORD>abcd123</PASSWORD>
</COMMAND>
```